# Does the PS5 controller support haptic feedback on PS3?

Tags: ps3, controllers, ps5

Does the PS5 dualsense controller have haptic feedback on PS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

According to [WIRED](https://www.wired.com/story/exclusive-playstation-5/):

> PS5 uses "highly programmable" voice-coil actuators to deliver vibration.

These little motors are the same kind of technology that allows speakers to vibrate and create sound, which means they're able to produce much more precise movements than the larger, spinning rumble motors.

What makes the PS5 controller's haptic feedback different is the nuance of its vibration motors. Inside each grip of a PS4 (and PS3) controller, there is a large motor with a half-moon-shaped weight, capable of spinning at various speeds and for various durations. These motors can help create immersion-enhancing vibration, but they're fairly crude and aren't able to start and stop very precisely. ([Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/ps5-controller-what-haptic-feedback-actually-does/))

Since old PS3 games are meant to work with old Dualshock controllers, they shouldn't fully exploit the new controller's technology.